# How many axons and dendrites are entering and exiting human male internal urethral sphincter?

Tags: neural-network

As I know, this information is not available yet. If indeed it is not available, this question may wait for future answers. I have known out that some parts of human connectome are already mapped, so it might be already available. I have looked some sites, and seems it is not easy to find it for me. So, by answers to this question, I will see, and other readers may see, how much this knowledge is available.

I think, this question may also get answers about whether borders of internal urethral sphincter are strictly defined, and about how to navigate to or access the connectome data.

Comment: While there is some overlap between biology and psychology when it comes to neurology, this question firmly belongs in the biology stack.  Unfortunately, it is too old to migrate (sorry I saw it so late), so I will just close, but you can repost it on biology.SE instead.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg why? i suspect real reason you close this is some site policy like avoiding passive pages / unanswered questions.

Comment: That is the reason I *looked* at it, but not the reason I closed it.  I'm open to discussion if you can explain how this question relates to cognition in any way.  I believe the latest resolution on neuro-anatomy questions belonging in biology.SE is [here](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/966/7001).